# Parsing lat and long from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, geocoding

I have a JSON file with lat and long in the incorrect format to call position {lat, lng} for map markers.

I'm trying to do a getJSON and for each incorrect lat and long, send it to a function that parses it into the correct format and add a marker to my map.

I'm not having any luck though. It comes in like
*"latLang": "27.8247427:-82.75040159999999"*

Here's a link to the JSON for reference. [JSON](http://cs1.utm.edu/~bbradley/map1/customers1.json)

Here's my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://cs1.utm.edu/~bbradley/map1/customers1.json", function(data) {
      const markers = data.map(({
        latLang
      }) => new google.maps.Marker({
        map: myMap,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseGeo(latLang))
      }));
    });
  });

  const parseGeo = str => { // this is to parse it into the right format
    const [lat, lng] = str.split(':').map(value => parseFloat(value, 10));
    return {
      lat,
      lng
    };
  }
```

Exert from JSON

```
[{
        "name": "Carole McKenzie",
        "address": "5720 80TH ST NORTH UNIT 310",
        "cityStateZip": "ST PETERSBURG, Florida 33709",
        "latLang": "27.8247427:-82.75040159999999",
        "image": "./people/MTI4MTYuanBn.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Matt Russell",
        "address": "1211 Miller Place Dr",
        "cityStateZip": "Bryant, Arkansas 72022-2389",
        "latLang": "34.606806:-92.5042948",
        "image": "./people/MTQ3OTUuanBn.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "George Thrapp",
        "address": "2906 Haddington Court",
        "cityStateZip": "North Chesterfield, Virginia 23224-5716",
        "latLang": "37.466937:-77.5075449",
        "image": "./people/MTk3NTkuanBn.jpg"
    },
```

Comment: Could you please show a working snippet, so we can have a better picture

Comment: We can't really get a working snippet since the URL refuses to serve SSL.

Comment: Just bypass the request and paste the example JSON response. Then go from there

Comment: I posted a snippet of the json. I hope that's what you all meant. I'm willing to post anything I have to though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance I think the problem you're running into *might* be that you're passing in two strings instead of an object with numeric `lat` and `lng` properties.

I think you can simplify it. Here's how I might go about such a thing:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Carole McKenzie",
    "address": "5720 80TH ST NORTH UNIT 310",
    "cityStateZip": "ST PETERSBURG, Florida 33709",
    "latLang": "27.8247427:-82.75040159999999",
    "image": "./people/MTI4MTYuanBn.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Matt Russell",
    "address": "1211 Miller Place Dr",
    "cityStateZip": "Bryant, Arkansas 72022-2389",
    "latLang": "34.606806:-92.5042948",
    "image": "./people/MTQ3OTUuanBn.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "George Thrapp",
    "address": "2906 Haddington Court",
    "cityStateZip": "North Chesterfield, Virginia 23224-5716",
    "latLang": "37.466937:-77.5075449",
    "image": "./people/MTk3NTkuanBn.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Trina Anderson",
    "address": "112 South Niles Avenue",
    "cityStateZip": "South Bend, Indiana 46617",
    "latLang": "41.6759656:-86.24418419999999",
    "image": "./people/NDExMTAuanBn.jpg"
  }
];

// utility function for turning the latLang string into an object with lat and lng properties, e.g.
// "41.6759656:-86.24418419999999" => {lat: 41.6759656, lng: -86.24418419999999}
const parseGeo = str => {
  const [lat, lng] = str.split(':').map(value => parseFloat(value, 10));
  return {
    lat,
    lng
  };
}

// convert all of the input items to lat/lng numeric props instead of latLang string
const parsed = data.map(({latLang, ...other}) => ({
  ...other,
  ...parseGeo(latLang)
}));

console.log(parsed);
```

From there you could iterate the parsed values and construct the markers:

```js
const markers = parsed.map(({lat, lng}) => (
  new google.maps.Marker({
    map: myMap,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat, lng})
  })
);
```

Or you could skip the pre-parsing and do the `parseGeo` conversion inline when creating the markers:

```js
const parseGeo = str => {
  const [lat, lng] = str.split(':').map(value => parseFloat(value, 10));
  return {
    lat,
    lng
  };
}

const markers = data.map(({latLang}) => (
  new google.maps.Marker({
    map: myMap,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseGeo(latLang))
  })
);
```

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but this is my first time working with javascript at all. You put const data = ....
How do I get the json into an array like that? Or did that happen automatically when I called the get function?

Comment: I'm just declaring the data inline so I don't have to make a request for external data just to demonstrate what follows. It's just the data from your ajax request. (The `data` argument that your `getJSON` callback receives.)

Comment: How would I call the functions on the json data? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Do it in the body of your getJSON callback. The “data” parameter is the parsed json object. `$.getJSON( url, function(data) { ... })`

Comment: Just add in the code or do I need to pass any parameters?

Comment: Are you still working on this? I can update my answer with more direct integration with what you’re doing if that’s helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I am. I'll edit my post to my latest attempt so you know where I'm at.

Comment: Okay, I updated it. Still no markers so I'm either calling your code wrong, Or I did something wrong elsewhere as well.

Comment: Your code resolved it. The problem was in how I was defining the map. myMap wasn't a variable.